# PYODBC corrupts utf8 data (reading from MYSQL information_schema DB)

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, odbc, pyodbc

**EDIT:**
I completely reworked this question to reflect my better understanding of the problem

The PYODBC+MYSQL command used to fetch all table names in my DB

```
cursor.execute("select table_name from information_schema.tables where
             table_schema='mydbname'")
```

The result is a list of unicode strings with **every second character omitted**, in each string.

The `information_schema` DB is utf8, although my table names are pure ascii. Reading from my DB which is latin1 works fine. Executing `set character_set_* = 'utf8'` does not help.

Executing the same query from a C++/ODBC test program works fine.

Do you know how `pyodbc` works wrt to character encoding? What encoding does it assume when working with a utf8 DB?

I work on Linux with UnixODBC, python 2.6.4, pyodbc 2.1.7

Comment: Why are you using ODBC for a local MySQL database, instead of the MySQLdb library?

Comment: @Daniel: this is a kind of "legacy" code, we've just switched to mysql from DB2. I'll look at this library, does it require the db to be local? I am not sure this will always be the case

Comment: No, it works fine with remote databases. I have no idea if it will solve your problem, but at least there'll be one fewer system in the way.

Comment: If you work on Windows you can try if it work with `odbc` module from win32 extensions (already included in ActiveState distributions).

Comment: @Michal: thanks, but I work on Linux...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODBC specification only allows two encodings: ASCII and UCS-2.  It is the job of the ODBC driver to convert whatever the database is in to one of those two, but I find most ODBC driver authors don't understand how it is supposed to work.

When a query is executed, pyodbc does not ask for any encoding.  It executes the query and then asks the driver for the data type of each column.  If the data type is Unicode, it will read the buffer and treat it as UCS2.  If the data type is ASCII, it will read the buffer and treat it as ASCII.

The storage format is supposed to be irrelevant.

Comment: thanks! BTW, I've found a workaround by using`cursor.execute("set character_set_results = 'latin1'")`. This still does not help if I do `cursor.tables()` which was there originally, though.