# Special characters are shown as question marks when downloading the data from SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, csv, pyodbc

I'm new to the Microsoft SQL database. I'm using pyodbc module in python to insert and download the data from the SQL Server database table. I've observed the special characters are stored as "?" (question marks).

String I'm loading to DB: 'TV 40″'.

String in the downloaded data from DB: 'TV 40?'

Please find the code to insert the data

```
def insert_record(table_name, op_rec):
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    #try:
    cursor, cnxn = create_conn()
    op_rec = remove_none(op_rec)
    if check_table_exists(cursor, table_name):
        pass
    else:
        fields = tuple(list(op_rec.keys()))
        create_table(cursor, table_name, fields)
        #print("Table created: " + table_name)

    row = list(op_rec.values())
    query = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES (""" % table_name
    query_data = add_parameters(query, tuple(row))
    query_data += ")"
    cursor.execute(query_data)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

`op_rec` in the above code is a dictionary.

I've tried changing the character sets of the database using the following methods. But none worked for me.

- [pyodbc doesn't correctly deal with unicode data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780705/pyodbc-doesnt-correctly-deal-with-unicode-data)
- [PYODBC corrupts utf8 data (reading from MYSQL information_schema DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056739/pyodbc-corrupts-utf8-data-reading-from-mysql-information-schema-db)

  - When I tried the above solution I got Incorrect syntax near '='. (102)

Can you please help with this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the schema of the table you're inserting data into? If you're attempting to store Unicode characters in it then those columns should be using the `nvarchar` data type. And the values you're inserting should be National character literals, e.g.: `N'TV 40″'` as opposed to `'TV 40″'`.

Comment: But really you should be using [Query Parameters](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) with `pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR` instead of using SQL Injection to construct your SQL query strings. Obligatory reference to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning,

Comment: Thanks much for your response. 1) Table schema is [(_id, int), (product_name, varchar(2000))]. 2) I'm storing a string, not Unicode characters so I'm not using nvarchar. 3) I've tried referring about National character literals. Is there any method which converts string into national character literals?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are using MySQL or (Microsoft) SQL Server. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @GordThompson I'm asking for Microsoft SQL. Edited the question also. Thanks much for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm storing a string, not Unicode characters so I'm not using nvarchar.

In Python_3, all strings are Unicode.

`varchar` columns use the single-byte character set (SBCS) defined for the database (or the table, if one is declared specifically for that table). If the (Unicode) character does not exist in the SBCS for that database/table then it is replaced with a question mark.

```py
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mssql_199;UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

print(
    crsr.execute(
        "SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name='test'"
    ).fetchval()
)
# SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

print(crsr.execute("SELECT CAST('TV 40″' AS varchar(2000))").fetchval())
# TV 40?
```

TL;DR - You can't store a character in a `varchar` column if the character set does not support it.